# Epiphany & Proxy Server

Tags: setup

Please can you tell me if there is a way to enter a proxy address and port to the Epiphany web browser so we can use the internet on our Raspberry Pi 2 in school.

Answer (score 1):

Given Epiphany is an integral part of Gnome, it uses the Gnome-wide system preferences.

> You can tell all applications on your system to use this tunnel through Gnome’s network-proxy interface. It is located under System>Preferences>Network Proxy.

#### References

1. [Super User Answer](https://superuser.com/a/57519/136002)

Comment: Thank you Alex for this answer. I have searched for Gnome but I can't see it anywhere - no shortcuts within GUI anyway. I tried the little cog in the top right hand corner. That has system, preferences but not proxy server. Should I be looking on the Pi itself or somewhere within Windows Server. Can you talk me in a bit.

Comment: GNOME is a [desktop environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)("DE"), much like LXDE, which is the default on the pi.  So if you are using Epiphany with LXDE instead, you may not have this control.  I suggest you ask about this kind of thing on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The default LXDE desktop environment on Raspbian does not allow you to set a proxy server. I have created a program called [pi-proxy](https://pi-proxy.net/) that allows you to enter a proxy server on your Raspberry Pi. This works for most software (including Epiphany).